# Flip-flopping text in tableview cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I am having a peculiar problem when I refresh my tableview. (I am using `UIRefreshControl`.) If I were to slow-mo what is happening:

Suppose there are 3 cells visible, A, B, and C, in that order from top to bottom.

1) I pull down and the tableview shows that it is refreshing.

2) A gets the text that should go in B. B gets the text that should go in C. C is off-screen.

3) Refresh ends and the table snaps back into place.

4) Incorrect text lingers for a second or so.

5) Each cell's text flips to the right thing.

The flip-flopping is pretty annoying to look at visually. Anyway, I feel like this is the kind of issue that can be fixed with a line of code that I just don't know about.

Here are excerpts of my code:

Function called when refresh occurs (gets records from CloudKit):

```
func refreshTable(sender: UIRefreshControl) {

    var postsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", VISIBILITY_CODE, WORLD) // default
    if sender.tag == 0 {
        postsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", VISIBILITY_CODE, WORLD)
    }
    else if sender.tag == 1 {
        postsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", VISIBILITY_CODE, PRIVATE)
    }
    else {
        // report problem
    }

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: POST, predicate: postsPredicate)
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
    query.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    self.db.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { records, error in
        if error == nil {
            self.list = [records!]
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.postTableView.reloadData()
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            })
        }
        else {
            if let error = error as? CKError {
                print(error)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Here's my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if self.list.count == 1 && self.list[0].count == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NO_POSTS, for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    let post = self.list[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: POST_IN_FEED_CELL, for: indexPath)

    if let postCell = cell as? PostInFeedTableViewCell {

        // deleted the assignment of values to other UI elements in my custom cell

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", LIBRARY_CODE, post.object(forKey: LIBRARY_CODE) as! String)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: LIBRARY_ITEM, predicate: predicate)
        self.db.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { records, error in
            if error == nil {
                let libraryItem = records?[0]
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                    postCell.title.text = libraryItem?.object(forKey: NAME) as! String

                })
            }
            else {
                if let error = error as? CKError {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

        }


    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Don't perform CKQuery operations *inside* `cellForRowAtIndexPath`; this function needs to execute quickly.  You should already have all of the data you need before the cell is displayed.  At the very least, put some sort of placeholder text or clear the text or display a spinner in the cell while you are waiting for the query to complete, but also use some sort of cache so you don't keep fetching the same data

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! That makes sense since `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has to execute so many times. Is that a side problem I have, or do you think it'll solve my flip-flopping problem as well? Thanks again!

Comment: Poor cell appearance problems are typically caused by cell reuse and since you don't reset the cell content before returning the cell object (the update happens later in the closure) I wouldn't be surprised if it is causing your problem